# How to set advanced tinymce in joomla 3 component

Tags: php, joomla, tinymce, joomla3.0, joomla-component

I call the editor and it apears, but it's extended version, which is set globaly for admin of whole page, and I want it to stay there that way.

But in my component I want an advance version of tinymce.

Here's code how i call tinymce:

```
$editor = JFactory::getEditor();
$editor =& JFactory::getEditor('tinymce');
$params = array(
    'mode' => 'advanced'
);
echo $editor->display('opis_long', $this->info['opis_long'], '10', '10', '1', '1', false, $params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// IMPORT EDITOR CLASS
jimport( 'joomla.html.editor' );

// GET EDITOR SELECTED IN GLOBAL SETTINGS
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$global_editor = $config->get( 'editor' );

// GET USER'S DEFAULT EDITOR
$user_editor = JFactory::getUser()->getParam("editor");

if($user_editor && $user_editor !== 'JEditor') {
    $selected_editor = $user_editor;
} else {
    $selected_editor = $global_editor;
}

// INSTANTIATE THE EDITOR
$editor = JEditor::getInstance($selected_editor);

// SET EDITOR PARAMS
$params = array( 'smilies'=> '0' ,
    'style'  => '1' ,
    'layer'  => '0' ,
    'table'  => '0' ,
    'clear_entities'=>'0',
    'mode' => '1'
);

// DISPLAY THE EDITOR (name, html, width, height, columns, rows, bottom buttons, id, asset, author, params)
echo $editor->display('opis_long', $this->info['opis_long'], '400', '400', '20', '20', true, null, null, null, $params);
```

core code from: [How to add joomla editor in custom component view but without using XML form fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064709/how-to-add-joomla-editor-in-custom-component-view-but-without-using-xml-form-fie)